# Toyota: Retension timing belt

Tags: toyota, timing-belt

(Toyota 2000 2.2L)
When a new timing belt is installed, the tension is set by a spring.  I'm wondering if belt needs to be retensioned at service intervals.  I have seen no mention of this, but it seems the tension should be adjusted as the belt ages.

Does Toyota recommend resetting the timing belt tension?

Answer (score 2):

The only maintenance you should have to do on a timing belt is replacement. First, the belt does not stretch very much if at all. Once the proper tension is set, it should be good for the life of the belt (usually either 60k or 100k miles, depending on the makeup of the belt itself). Secondly, the spring will take up any slack which **might** occur due to stretching. Other timing belt systems use a pressurized oil tensioner to do this job.